# How i return custom text in Laravel 5.2 query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables:

**qr_details table:**

```
id   qrcode_id  prize_id   created_at           updated_at
12   1          12         2017-10-06 19:53:10  0000-00-00 00:00:0
```

**qrcodes table:**

```
id   correspond_code    qrcode_note    created_at             updated_at

1    plgt73g            X Batch        2017-10-06 21:55:11    2017-09-28 08:57:53   
2    gs35dn4            Y Batch        2017-10-06 21:55:22    2017-10-04 04:38:50
3    df324f3            X Batch        2017-10-06 21:55:36    2017-10-06 13:29:11
```

Now i want if i get `qrcodes` table `id` in `qr_details` table `qrcode_id` column then it will show text `Yes` other than it will show `No`. How i write this? Thanks in advance.

I have tried so far:

```
$drawOr = DB::table('qr_details')
        ->leftJoin('qrcodes', 'qr_details.qrcode_id', '=', 'qrcodes.id')
        ->where('qrcode_id','=', $id)
        ->get();
        dd($drawOr);
```

its shows an error.

Comment: are you getting integrity constraint error ?

Comment: why don't you use eloquent relation for this?

Comment: I'm really having a hard time understanding this question. Presumably `qr_details` is a table with details about a row of `qrcodes` ? How would the `id` not be there?

Comment: @apokryfos if anyone draw qr code then qr_details table will be fill into. That's why qr_details table have one row. other is not be drawn yet.

Comment: @GauravGupta i am getting https://prnt.sc/guc1gm this error.

Comment: dd your $id what i'll return ?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. You can use this code in controller:-

```
$drawOr = DB::table('qrcodes')
    ->get();

foreach($drawOr as $key => $draw){
    $getqrDeatilCount = DB::table('qr_details')->where('qrcode_id',$draw->id)->count();
    if($getqrDeatilCount > 0){
        $drawOr[$key]->status = "Yes";
    }else{
        $drawOr[$key]->status = "No";
   }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($drawOr);
```

Now i have created the new key i.e. **status** that contains the value in 'yes' or no
and after that you can use in blade file according to your requirement..
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, I am looking for this kind of .. Thanks : )

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DB::raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) in `select()` something like

```
$drawOr = DB::table('qr_details')
        ->select('qr_details.*',
          DB::raw("(CASE WHEN qrcodes.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS somealias"))
        ->leftJoin('qrcodes', 'qr_details.qrcode_id', '=', 'qrcodes.id')
        ->where('qrcode_id','=', $id)
        ->get();
```

Comment: I think this is the other way around. The qrcodes table is the base table and the one `qr_details` are the related table and OP wants to see whether for each `qrcode` there's an entry in the `qr_details` table

Comment: `qr_details` table don't need any entry. It will fill up when anyone draw qr code of `qrcodes` table.

Comment: `->where('qrcode_id','=', 1)` it is printing Yes. But if i put  `->where('qrcode_id','=', 2)` then it is blank. It should be `No`. I think you almost there.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud provide your table definitions and some relevant sample data set to produce issue for qrcode_id = 2, It would be better if you can add your schema and data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and provide us the link for your sample data